# 3DsMax's Optimize tool in Blender

Tags: modeling, retopology

I've been looking for something similar to 3Dsmax's Optimize too, Maybe an addon. Being able to connect verts by holding and dragging over the topology on the fly or holding another button to weld or target weld would be nice.

Just to be clear I don't mean to use the knife tool, or to have to select verts then connect, or switch tools in general. Looking for an option that helps with the speed of triangulating, welding, and target welding and generally optimizing a game topology.

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: are you talking about the remesh tool that takes the whole geometry and converts it into uniform quad geometry?

Comment: No. The optimize tool is just a tool that can help with those things I've mentioned without selecting sub-object components. Just move around hold buttons and slash to connect, weld, target weld, and move. This is an essential tool  for lowpoly game modeling that substantially speeds up work.

Comment: Suggest to describe in detail what it does exactly... eg. *How* and *Why* it speeds up welding and triangulation.

Comment: you can use the decimate modifier for that

Answer (score 0):

So ,You have not given enough detail to work with but you have given the name **Optimize tool** so i did some search and found this on Autodesk's site

> The ProOptimizer feature is an optimization tool that helps you reduce the number of vertices (and so the number of faces) in an object while preserving the object's appearance.

so that can be done using a modifier in blender which is not an addon and is available by default known as a Decimate modifier that reduce geometry and tries to preserve geometry

**Some example**

**This is a 24 thousand vertices cube**

[image]

**This is the same cube after decimating**

[image]